# c# rewrite url postback issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting

I'm trying to rewrite the URL in my project and it works fine

Ex.
the original URL is 
**http://localhost:50260/u_SaleCom/Product.aspx?Status=Create**
and I rewrite it to **http://localhost:50260/u_SaleCom/Product/Create**
by using code in web.config

```
 <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="rewrite to u_SaleCom Product pages 1 QueryString" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^u_SaleCom/Product/([a-zA-Z0-9=]+)" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="u_SaleCom/Product.aspx?Status={R:1}" />
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
```

so until now everything works fine, but when page postback by clicking any button or using AutoPostBack in DropDownList the page URL will change to 
**http://localhost:50260/u_SaleCom/Product/Create?Status=Create**
and that happens only if the URL is rewritten.

I try to search on the internet for a solution and I didn't find the right one.

I found here some questions with the same issue but also it's not helping me

[ASP.NET postbacks creates issue in URL rewriting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191612/asp-net-postbacks-creates-issue-in-url-rewriting)

[rewrite url. asp.net c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2370207/rewrite-url-asp-net-c-sharp)

[PostBack Url in Rewriting Url using UrlRewriting.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6497096/postback-url-in-rewriting-url-using-urlrewriting-net)

Comment: Properties in the URL after the question mark are options so changing Status=Create to a subfolder /Create is wrong.  You would need a new webpage called Create.

Comment: sorry, @jdweng I didn't understand you, and I don't know if you understand me. I mention that webpage is work fine with the rewrite, the issue is when it postback

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ,

```
$( window ).load(function() {Store Value Here });
```

The Rewrite URL Store in .load event Jquery and it will posses the value on post back.

Comment: Dear @Muhammad-ali  could you please give me more explain

Comment: Due to post back the rewrite value become lost, so we use load event from jquery to preserve the value , when u store value in load event it will remain unchanged with post back.

Comment: or you can load value on pageload () in code behind.